# How to create a tool with my desktop icons?

Tags: c#

On my desktop I have a lot of icons which can't be remove. If I try to delete them when I restart the computer these appear again. So I want to create an interface where to put all this icons and to organised them.

Someone can give me an idea how to start? I putted on tags C# but if someone knows and wants can give me another idea I'm ready to put in practice.

Comment: do you mean the bin folder? they can be removed in the settings...

Comment: actually I don't want to remove them because these are useful, but what I want to do is to create an interface and there to move all this icons. If I will do this  I will have a single app not a lot of icons

Comment: do you mean system files like thumbs.db? They can be hidden in File Explorer Options

Comment: I think this is more suited to http://superuser.com/.